# How to cast volatile int** to void**

Tags: c++, c, casting

I have this old C - code that my compiler is warning me about (old C-style cast).

```
volatile uint32_t* map;
void** argForSomeAPIfunction = (void**)&map;
```

How can I convert this to C++ cast style? I need to convert volatile uint32_t** to void**.

The reason why I need this is that there is a closed-source vendor API that expects me to pass a void** pointer. I cannot change that function signature. On the other hand, the vendor told me that I can access this map of registers, that are always 32-bit, using a pointer to uint32_t, and he provided me the working example in C-style, that used `(void**)&`. I tried this C-example and it's working fine.

Side note: This vendor API communicates with a PCIe card, via a custom kernel module. There are two options two read the internal memory of the PCIe card, using a safe API function that uses "ioctl" and built-in checks, or using an unsupervised access to this 32-bit register map, that is initialized by calling to `API::InitializeRegisterMap((void**)&map);`. This is done only once, at the very beginning of the program. After that, I access directly the memory using `map[offset]`, where offset goes in steps of 4 bytes, instead of the supervised function `API::ReadRegister(offset)` that in some cases is slower and critically delays the data acquisition (while the card is doing other tasks). The computer does not change the register contents, it just reads those. The external independent card can change at any time the register content, which is why the keyword volatile was introducted in the example from the vendor, I believe.

Comment: What you're doing is **always** an invalid cast and the code is incorrect.

Comment: I wish I could see more context, since this `volatile uint32_t* map;` doesn't smell well and second line make it worse.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I would be helped (OP as well) if you briefly point out why

Comment: I added more context now. The C-code comes from an example from the vendor, I tried it and it is working, same result than full supervised function, but faster.

Comment: Your vendor appears to be incompetent. "Casting away" `volatile` is always an undefined behavior bug, which in turn can lead to incorrect machine code getting generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for initialization, then I guess what it does is **fill** in a `void *`, not anything else, i.e. as if in C++ you'd have a parameter of type `void *&`.

I believe it is intended to be used as

```
void *ptr;
if (API::InitializeRegisterMap(&ptr)) {
    ...
}
```

then *afterwards* you will take the value in `ptr` and convert *that* value **to** `volatile uint32_t *map`:

```
void *ptr;
volatile std::uint32_t *map;
if (API::InitializeRegisterMap(&ptr)) {
    map = static_cast<std::uint32_t *>(ptr);
}
```

Most notably in **C**, as opposed to C++, this can be written **completely castless**, which should be considered a good sign.

Also, you want to avoid `reinterpret_cast` like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a volatile to a void * is valid in some specific circumstances, e.g.
the pointer is shared between multiple threads using suitable lock synchronisation, but for each thread it appears to be a volatile type *.

At a later time, the pointer has to be passed to a C function like free() which takes a non-volatile void *. (Again, we assume suitable synch mechanisms between the threads). At this point, the volatile type * has to be cast to a non-volatile void *. This is perfectly reasonable behaviour, as the pointer is presented in different contexts in different portions of the code.

At least that is the case for single *, if you are talking about ** pointers like here then there are still valid circumstances, but they would have to very specific cases, and not the general case.

Answer (score -1):

After several trial and error steps, I noticed that this cannot be done with a simple cast step, you need to concatenate two:

```
void** argForSomeAPIfunction = reinterpret_cast<void**>(const_cast<uint32_t**>(&map));
```

The inner one is needed to cast away the volatile-ness, the second one for converting from int to void.

Comment: there are many ways you can cast one pointer to another, but whether you end up with a valid pointer is a different question. You can cast the resulting pointer back to its original type, but I have doubts whether you can do anything else with it

Comment: I gave more context now in my question. I need to cast this pointer to void**, I cannot do it in any other way because the API comes from the vendor and is closed. I am just trying to adapt the example given by the vendor from C to C++. For the moment, I tested both versions and they both seem to work, but of course it might be that there are some corner cases where this unsupervised access function is not well defined.

Comment: Either the original pointer is `volatile` for a reason, in which case you simply can't cast. Or it isn't `volatile` for any good reason, in which case you need to remove it. In either case, this is the wrong solution.

Comment: Your perceived need for this is unclear, but do make sure that you understand that a `void **` is *not* a generic double pointer in the sense that `void *` is a generic single pointer.  A `void **` points to an object that is specifically a `void *`, and not any other type.

Comment: John, I cannot change the vendor-API, it expects a void** and they ensure me that they work behind the scenes with it as if it were 32-bit data (yes, they should ask instead for int** as parameter, but this is something I cannot change).
What I could though change is the access example they gave me. @Lundin, do you suggest that it would be better to just use instead, without the volatile:
uint32_t* map; void** argForSomeAPIfunction = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&map); ?

Comment: You tell me. _Why is it volatile_?

Comment: It's volatile because the 32-bit registers of this PCIe external device change completely independently from the actions run on computer. The computer just maps to those addresses (via the kernel module) and the external device register content themself might change at any time, independently of what the C++ code is doing on the computer. The fact that a void** cast is needed is just due to the unfortunate function signature of the API, it is only needed in the very beginning to initialize the pointer to the right point. It is never used again later on, so to me volatile makes sense.